# How to set user role without being overwritten by new users logging in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, roles

I'm working on a web app that already has Microsoft Authentication through OAuth2. It includes a Role.cs class, that's then used in the server to send everyone to their respective pages/areas, based on their roles. However, lets say user A logs in and is a Teacher, the Role.userRole is set to Teacher, and they go to the Teacher Page. When user B logs in, a student, the Role.userRole is set to Student, and they go to the Student Page. However, it seems that when User B (student) logs in, it changes the Role.userRole globally for everyone online. So when User A (teacher) hits refresh, they get redirected to the Students Page, since the server is seeing the Role.userRole set as Student. This, in turn, creates a conflict when using the Role.userRole and Role.userName, since it mismatches database entries to their real creator, and it redirects users to pages they shouldn't access based on their roles.

I have done some troubleshooting here and there and found where the page actually sets the Role.userRole value. It's in the Startup.Auth.cs.

I have included the code for the Role definition and the setting in Startup.Auth.cs:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfP5l.jpg

The ideal behavior would be that is sets the Role for the user at login, but just for that user, not all connected users.

I appreciate any help, thanks!

-AxelSariel

Comment: Don't use `static` fields to store information pertinent only to a single request.

Comment: What @Dai said. Static means you give the property a specific memory slot(s) to be used for the duration of the application's life. Meaning your server will write to that slot instead of a new, dynamically assigned one, which kind of beats the purpose in your case.

Comment: Ahh ok, I understand! Given that, what can I change it to so it only changes for each user separately? Should I still use the Role.cs class or do I need to use other methods for storing it? Thanks for the help!